# can not connect with aws iot mqtt broker using android client

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I can not connect with AWS iot when I'm going to create new key and certificate.

It gives me error as under:

> com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::964546574005:assumed-role/Cognito_GTekPool3Unauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials
>   is not authorized to perform:
>
> iot:CreateKeysAndCertificate on resource: * (Service: AWSIot; Status
>   Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID:
>   b1c4acdd-b1ba-11e8-9d83-772e33c0d6b2)

Below is what I have done in code:

```
if (clientKeyStore == null) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Cert/key was not found in keystore - creating new key and certificate.");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Create a new private key and certificate. This call
                    // creates both on the server and returns them to the
                    // device.
                    CreateKeysAndCertificateRequest createKeysAndCertificateRequest =
                            new CreateKeysAndCertificateRequest();
                    createKeysAndCertificateRequest.setSetAsActive(true);
                    final CreateKeysAndCertificateResult createKeysAndCertificateResult;
                    createKeysAndCertificateResult =
                            mIotAndroidClient.createKeysAndCertificate(createKeysAndCertificateRequest);
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG,
                            "Cert ID: " +
                                    createKeysAndCertificateResult.getCertificateId() +
                                    " created.");

                    // store in keystore for use in MQTT client
                    // saved as alias "default" so a new certificate isn't
                    // generated each run of this application
                    AWSIotKeystoreHelper.saveCertificateAndPrivateKey(certificateId,
                            createKeysAndCertificateResult.getCertificatePem(),
                            createKeysAndCertificateResult.getKeyPair().getPrivateKey(),
                            keystorePath, keystoreName, keystorePassword);

                    // load keystore from file into memory to pass on
                    // connection
                    clientKeyStore = AWSIotKeystoreHelper.getIotKeystore(certificateId,
                            keystorePath, keystoreName, keystorePassword);


                    // Attach a policy to the newly created certificate.
                    // This flow assumes the policy was already created in
                    // AWS IoT and we are now just attaching it to the
                    // certificate.
                    AttachPrincipalPolicyRequest policyAttachRequest =
                            new AttachPrincipalPolicyRequest();
                    policyAttachRequest.setPolicyName(AWS_IOT_POLICY_NAME);
                    policyAttachRequest.setPrincipal(createKeysAndCertificateResult
                            .getCertificateArn());
                    mIotAndroidClient.attachPrincipalPolicy(policyAttachRequest);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            btnConnect.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG,
                            "Exception occurred when generating new private key and certificate.",
                            e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

View.OnClickListener connectClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "clientId = " + clientId);

        try {
            mqttManager.connect(clientKeyStore, new AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(final AWSIotMqttClientStatus status,
                        final Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Status = " + String.valueOf(status));

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (status == AWSIotMqttClientStatus.Connecting) {
                                tvStatus.setText("Connecting...");

                            } else if (status == AWSIotMqttClientStatus.Connected) {
                                tvStatus.setText("Connected");

                            } else if (status == AWSIotMqttClientStatus.Reconnecting) {
                                if (throwable != null) {
                                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Connection error.", throwable);
                                }
                                tvStatus.setText("Reconnecting");
                            } else if (status == AWSIotMqttClientStatus.ConnectionLost) {
                                if (throwable != null) {
                                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Connection error.", throwable);
                                }
                                tvStatus.setText("Disconnected");
                            } else {
                                tvStatus.setText("Disconnected");

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Connection error.", e);
            tvStatus.setText("Error! " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

Certificate from keystore is not reading and giving me IOexception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::964546574005:assumed-role/Cognito_GTekPool3Unauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform:
```

indicates that you have missing permission for the specified role. You will have to attach a valid policy which allows you to call the `createKeysAndCertificate` API on the service.

Comment: Hi Rohan, how can I attach a valid policy which allows you to call the createKeysAndCertificate API on the service. I try adding `- iot:CreateKeysAndCertificate` in serverless.yaml file, but it doesn't work. Thank you